# At what frequencies do you usually high/low pass male vocal doubles?

Tags: frequency

I'm speaking in general but if it depends on the vocal how can I find out by ear?

Comment: I generally don't. I generally mulitband comp entire sections if we're talking large block BVs. Why do you think you'd need to?

Comment: I did one of my usual long, waffling opinionated answers on some tips & tricks for doubling & blocking vocals. Doesn't answer your question but you might find it interesting - https://music.stackexchange.com/a/109701/12556

Comment: Haha - it was an answer to one of your own questions ;)))

Answer (score 1):

For all high pass and low pass filters for any instrument or voice:

Start with the filter turned on but at the end of its range (as low as possible for high pass, as high as possible for low pass). Listen to the track either soloed or with the music, depending on why you are filtering it. Slowly raise (lower) the filter until it makes the track sound bad and overly filtered. Then lower (raise) it slightly until it just stops sounding bad or wrong. Done.

How do you know when it sounds bad/wrong/too much? Vision and experience. It’s a combination of having a vision or plan for how you want the track to sound and the experience to know what that plan sounds like in each element of it.

If you feel like you don’t have enough of a plan or enough experience, then just give it your best shot and you can always go back and change it later as you mix. Doing it even when you aren’t sure exactly what you’re doing is how you get the experience.

Comment: I'm conflicted by this answer. There isn't any part of it I disagree with, but I have the uncomfortable feeling that in its execution there is greater chance of error than in not doing it at all...

Comment: @Tetsujin I wonder if you and I would agree on what “error” means in this case. If it sounds good, it is good. My take on where the asker is in their journey of mixing is they still have yet to learn how to learn how to mix. So my answer isn’t about how to mix, it’s about how to learn how to mix.

Comment: I do agree, & by 'error' I just mean there are more ways to get this wrong than right.. It's just that a feel this is too far beyond 'mixing 101' & more of a 5th year experience gainer ;) I remember my first 10 years of mixing I spent more time taking cassettes out to the car to try figure where i went wrong than anything else ;)